# How to improve accuracy of the large Milvus Index?

Tags: nlp, llama-index, vector-database, milvus

We are using the Milvus index with 300K documents. The accuracy of the results is not good. When we use the small index of around 30K the accuracy of the results was good. How to improve the accuracy for a larger Milvus index?